# How to get the texts of elements in an IAccessible whose role is a list

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, accessibility

I am developing an app like Narrator (a program that reads text from some windows). The platform is Windows.

I use Microsoft Active Accessibility to implement this function. I had a window that displayed some messages. Narrator could read them out as "IEMsgView ...(the messages contained)" I soon got the `IAccessible` interface of this Accessible Object "IEMsgView". And I confirmed that there is only one such object by comparing its name and location.

```
// Let IAccessible *pList represent the one I got.
```

By calling `pList->get_accChildCount()` I acknowledged that it had several childs. Yet `pList->get_accChild()` returns `S_FALSE` when I passed it a valid child ID, which meant that its childs were elements and `pList` itself contained information about them, according to MSDN.

However, after called every method of `pList` that could give me something I still couldn't have the messages the window displayed. But Narrator did read them out! So there must be some way to obtain it.

Could someone please tell me how can I obtain these messages? Do I need `IAccessible` or something else?

Comment: IAccessible is legacy. Why don't you use UI Automation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility-and-ui-automation-compared

Comment: @Simon Mourier Thank you! I will try it.